# GDAL 2.4.2 installation problem in Debian

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I have built GDAL 2.4.2 in Debian package through the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-all-dev
wget https://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.4.2/gdal-2.4.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz gdal-2.4.2.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.4.2
./configure --with-python
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

No error shows during building. Now `ogr2ogr` command is not working and returning `-bash: /usr/bin/ogr2ogr: No such file or directory`. Whereas it is showing that gdal is installed if I asking for the version `gdalinfo --version`. It's returning `GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28`.

How can I get rid of this in my Debian server?

Comment: did you restart the service or log off and on again?

Comment: No. I don't know how to start or restart the GDAl service.

Comment: sorry that's an auto correct error - should have said did you restart the server

Comment: No. I am in a production environment. Is it highly necessary?

Comment: logging off and on again should do it

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to refresh your path somehow, sometimes running `rehash` will do it, alternatively log off and log on again will work.